# VM Created from Image with Azure Powershell does not set ComputerName

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have an Azure Image, which when I use Azure Powershell to create a VM from, despite me setting the ComputerName in the script, the VM is created without setting the ComputerName to the provided value.

Script:

```
$ImageName = 'MyImage'
$RsgName = 'MyRsg'
$VmName = 'MyNewVM'
$DiagnosticStorageName = 'diagnosticsstore5048'

$cred = Get-Credential -Credential 'TheAdmin'

$Image = Get-AzureRmImage -ImageName $ImageName -ResourceGroupName $RsgName

# Get NIC
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $RsgName

# Configure the new VM
$Vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VmName -VMSize 'Standard_A2_v2'
$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $Vm -Id $Image.Id
$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $Vm -Name $VmName'-disk' -StorageAccountType 'StandardLRS' -DiskSizeInGB '128' -CreateOption FromImage -Caching ReadWrite
$Vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $Vm -Id $nic.Id
$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -VM $Vm -Enable -ResourceGroupName $RsgName -StorageAccountName $DiagnosticStorageName
$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $Vm -Windows -ComputerName 'dor' -Credential $Cred -ProvisionVMAgent

New-AzureRmVM -VM $Vm -ResourceGroupName $RsgName -Location 'West Europe' -DisableBginfoExtension
```

Last time I run the script to create the VM, it left the new VM with a computer name of 'WIN-I80O6J22ENS'
The Image was created as per the process here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json

**UPDATE**
Alot of people think that I am not Generalizing the image correctly, so I wanted to add here how I am doing it.
Inside the VM I run:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $env:windir\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe -ArgumentList "/generalize /oobe /shutdown /unattend:$env:windir\System32\Sysprep\unattend.xml"
```

Unattend.xml only has one setting in it which is to step the TimeZone.

Once this is completed and the VM OS has shut down, I run the following to get the VM, stop it, and set it to Generalized:

```
# Shutdown Source VM & Generalize
$SourceVM = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $SourceRsg -Name $SourceVMName
$Null = Stop-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $SourceRsg -Name $SourceVMName -Force
Write-Host 'Stopped Source VM'

Set-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $SourceRsg -Name $SourceVMName -Generalized
Write-Host 'Set Source VM to Generalized'
```

I have noticed that when the last command is ran, the output is:

> OperationId :
>   Status      :
>   StartTime   :
>   EndTime     :
>   Error       :

It doesn't actually say if it was successful or not?

After this I create the Image from the VM disk.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the image not being **"Generalized"**.

Take a look at the [Create a managed image of a generalized VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json) guide.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The image was Generalized, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specialized image, the Computer name will be missing because the old computer name and the new computer name share the same RID and SID number and on a ideal situation each virtual machine deployment has different RID and SID number. The Computer name can be displayed if the image is a generalized.

Check this article for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

Comment: The image was Generalized, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Use this code to check if the image is truly generalized or specialized


`(Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName <resource-group> -Name <vm-name>).StorageProfile.OsDisk`

If the CreateOption: FromImage ; the image is properly generalized but if the CreateOption: Attach ; the image is not correctly generalized.

If the the CreateOption: FromImage,  you could try to redeploy the virtual machine. Hope this helps

Comment: So I created a VM from my image, and once the VM was created and before doing anything else, I ran '(Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName <resource-group> -Name <vm-name>).StorageProfile.OsDisk', which told me 'CreateOption       : FromImage', but the computer name was not set to 'dor'

Comment: During the image creation, Is the Osstate specified as Generalized, 
`Set-AzureRmImageOsDisk -Image $imageConfig -OsState Generalized -OsType Windows -ManagedDiskId $diskID` 
to check if the image you used in creating the disk is Generalized; use:

`(Get-AzureRmImage -ResourceGroupName <rg-name> -ImageName <image-name>).StorageProfile.OsDisk`

Check the staus of the OSStae if its truly generalized.. You can always set a new computer name in as much the image used is generalized.

Comment: Running (Get-AzureRmImage -ResourceGroupName <rg-name> -ImageName <image-name>).StorageProfile.OsDisk against my image tells me: OsState            : Generalized

Answer (score 0):

The point everyone is trying to make, from your description of the issue, it seems the Image was not generalized correctly or aspect of the generalization failed.

The script work fine on my end, so the only issue is with the image. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYae6.png)

Try another deployment from that image an see is you get the same computer name (WIN-I80O6J22ENS).

If you get the same name that is a sure confirmation of issue with generalization.

If the name changes it might mean that the machine you imaged has a policy that is not accepting the name 'dor' so the system is generating default name.

Either way issue is not with the Powershell or Azure. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried another deployement from the Image, this time I got a computer name of 'WIN-5LTGQBDHG29'

Comment: I have updated the main post with how the Image is being done, this used to work fine and my process hasn't changed, I think I read somewhere the other week that if you use an image to create a VM, then generalize and create and image from that, and keep doing that over and over, eventually it stops setting the computer name

Comment: You should not specify an '/unattend' switch, i believe that is whats causing the issue.  sysprep without that switch an you should be fine.

Comment: But /unattend is needed to pass in the unattend.xml location? And I need this file to tell it what to set the TimeZone to.

Comment: The file means that all OS configuration including Computername is going to be taken from that file.  When it doesn't file computername in file, it just generates a default one.